# Laravel not rendering form element, but only the contents inside

Tags: laravel

I have been stumped on this for a couple hours and can not figure a way around it.
Larvel 8 with Livewire

I have a very basic form.

```
<form action="/dashboard/payment" method="POST">
        @csrf
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary my-3 w-100" id="checkout-button">
            
            <span wire:loading>Please Wait</span>
            <span wire:loading.remove>Pay - $
                <span>100</span>
                <br>
                <small>Description of payment</small>
            </span>
            
        </button>
        
      </form>
```

But the form tag itself it is not rendering the html. It is only rendering the button inside.

When incrementing a value with another button, the form tag is then rendered into html and the button can be used as expected.

The incrementing button only ++ to a value and updates the database with the new value.

This is the only thing holding me back, I have searched everywhere but cant find any information about form tags not rendering.

Note: Neither the opening  tag or the closing tag  is rendered until the other button is pressed.

Any ideas or information would be fantastic and greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a SINGLE root element in your component view?

Comment: Check the page in "view-source" (not inspector) to see if the tags are sent by PHP to the browser. Sometimes they can be sent but the browser may choose to omit them due to bad HTML syntax before them or something like that

Comment: @Snapey the form is in the middle of the single root element.

Comment: I don't understand "But the form tag itself it is not rendering the html. It is only rendering the button inside."  The form only contains the button?  Make sure you do not have nested forms.